# Success Message is not showing in jQuery Ajax Success

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'contact-us.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
       name: name.val()
    }, success: function (response) {
       alert("Success");
    }, error: function(res){
       alert("Error");
    }
});
```

I am sending a POST request. POST request is successful. Saving data perfectly. But from Ajax it's giving **Error** alert. What is the problem?

POST request is in the same page.

Comment: Use the documented arguments for the error callback to find out what the error status and error message tell you and update question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The response from contact-us.php file may not be a json.
In such a case remove dataType:'json' from your request.

If you are expecting JSON then verify is response a proper JSON string.

Comment: But what if they are expecting json and it is a back end problem? This approach is based on assumptions that require clarifications